# android canvas draw text in the triangle

Tags: android, canvas, android-custom-view, android-drawable, android-bitmap

[image]

In this Image I want text to totally be in the triangle with `CYAN` color.
I have created my own `ImageView`:

```
public class BookImageView extends android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView {

private static final Float DISCOUNT_SIDE_SIZE = 0.33333F;

private Bitmap bitmap;

private Paint drawPaint = new Paint();
private Paint trianglePaint = new Paint();

{
    trianglePaint.setColor(Constants.DISCOUNT_COLOR);
    trianglePaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
    trianglePaint.setShadowLayer(10.0f, 10.0f, 10.0f, Color.parseColor("#7f000000"));
    trianglePaint.setAntiAlias(true);

    drawPaint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    drawPaint.setTypeface(Typeface.create(Typeface.DEFAULT, Typeface.BOLD));
    drawPaint.setShadowLayer(1f, 0f, 1f, Color.BLACK);
}

// Constractors ...    

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    if (bitmap != null) {
        Bitmap tempBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
        Canvas tempCanvas = new Canvas(tempBitmap);
        tempCanvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, null);

        Path path = new Path();
        path.setFillType(Path.FillType.EVEN_ODD);

        float size = bitmap.getWidth() * DISCOUNT_SIDE_SIZE;

        path.lineTo(size, 0);
        path.lineTo(0, size);
        path.lineTo(0, 0);
        path.close();

        tempCanvas.drawPath(path, trianglePaint);

        float scale = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;

        drawPaint.setTextSize((int) (14 * scale));

        Rect textBounds = new Rect();
        drawPaint.getTextBounds("50%", 0, "50%".length(), textBounds);
        int x = (int) (size / 2) - textBounds.width() / 2;
        int y = (int) (size / 2) - textBounds.height() / 2;

        tempCanvas.save();
        tempCanvas.rotate(-45, x, y);
        tempCanvas.drawText("50%", x, y, drawPaint);
        tempCanvas.restore();

        setImageDrawable(new BitmapDrawable(getContext().getResources(), tempBitmap));
    }
}

@Override
public void setImageBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {
    this.bitmap = bitmap;
    invalidate();
}
```

}

what can I do to solve this problem ?

Comment: reduce text size?

Comment: Try drawing in a non rotated triangle and then rotating the complete view by 45 degree

Comment: @SunnyKumarAditya thanks for answer . but not worked

Comment: Can you share the code and outcome snapshot. Will dig in when I get time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this

1) Measure the width of your text 
Use [measureText](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Paint.html#measureText(java.lang.String,%20int,%20int))

2) From the point you are drawing calculate the width remaining to draw

3) Now depending on the use case you can curtail the length of text or scale the text as needed

```
    int textWidthRequired = (int) drawPaint.measureText(textToDraw);
    int widthRemainingToDraw = totalWidth/2 - textDrawX;
    if(textWidthRequired > widthRemainingToDraw){
        //handling 
    }
    // draw text
   tempCanvas.drawText(textToDraw,textDrawX, textDrawY, drawPaint);
```

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how high up you want the text to be, you can use properties of similar triangles to first determine the maximum width of the text.  In your case, size = the triangle's base, and size = the triangle's height/altitude.  Let's define two variables:
Correction:  The altitude won't be equal to the base. You'd need to calculate the altitude in order to use the below solution.

```
float triangleBase = size; // triangle base
float triangleAltitude = size; // Calculate this.
```

Let's say we want the text to be halfway up the center of the triangle:

```
float textYHeight = triangleHeight/2;
```

We figure out the width of the triangle at this point by using the following formula since the sides of similar triangles are proportional: 
baseOfTriangleA/baseOfTriangleB = altitudeOfTriangleA/altitudeOfTriangleB;

```
float triangleWidthAtTextYLocation = (textYHeight * triangleBase)/triangleAltitude;
```

Now that we know what the width of the triangle is at this location, we can just iterate through different text scales until the text width is less than the value triangleWidthAtTextYlocation.

```
        float scale = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;

        int scaleFactor = 0;
        drawPaint.setTextSize((int) (scaleFactor * scale));
        Rect textBounds = new Rect();
        drawPaint.getTextBounds("50%", 0, "50%".length(), textBounds);
        while(textBounds.length < triangleWidthAtTextYLocation){
             // Re-measure the text until it exceeds the width
             scaleFactor++;
             drawPaint.setTextSize((int) (scaleFactor * scale));
             drawPaint.getTextBounds("50%", 0, "50%".length(), textBounds);
         }

         // Once we know the scaleFactor that puts it over the width of the triangle
         // at that location, we reduce it by 1 to be just under that width:
         scaleFactor = Maths.abs(scaleFactor - 1);
         // final text size:
         drawPaint.setTextSize((int) (scaleFactor * scale));
```